# How to auto create columns with name using css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am currently creating my 8 col grid using the built in css-grid like this

```
.post{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [col1]1fr [col2]1fr [col3] 1fr [col4] 1fr  [col5] 1fr [col6]1fr [col7] 1fr [col8]1fr [col-end];
  grid-template-rows: [row1-start]1fr [row2-start]1fr [row3-start]1fr[row3-end];
  grid-row-gap: 16px;
}
```

What I want to do is to auto create the grid without having to specify the width for all columns, since they all have the same width.
I was thinking that I could use [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) like this:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(8, [col1][col2][col3][col4][col5][col6][col7][col8] 1fr);
```

but it does not work. How would I go about simplifying the definition of my grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate the column names using `grid-template-areas` and set the column widths after that.

```css
.post {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  
}

.post > div {
  background: #ccc; 
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
</div>
```